# MySQL Filtrar Permisos Vencidos

Tags: java, mysql, mysqli, javafx, mysql-workbench

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Tengo una tabla en mysql llamada conductores en la cual guardo sus datos incluyendo Fecha de Expedida la licencia de conducir y Fecha de expiracion. Lo que necesito es filtrar "Mostrar" todas las que esten por vencer o ya hayan vencido. en mi pais vencen cada 4 años.
aqui muestro mi tabla:
[image: Licencias]

Comment: Podrías añadir qué has intentado. Por lo pronto, investiga el uso de la función DATEDIFF. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta sentencia:

```
SELECT licenciaexpedida
    , licenciaexpira
    , CASE WHEN  locenciaexpira > DATE_ADD(licenciaexpedida, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
        THEN 'Expirada' ELSE 'Vigente' END
FROM TuTabla
```

Saludos.